# What are complimentary baking items for a small 22L Oven Toaster Griller (OTG) without a convection fan?

Tags: baking, oven

This is the kind of 22L OTG I'm referring to. Many videos exist, which can give you an indication of it's size:
[image]

It has three baking racks. Operates at 1200W. Has a baking tray, wire grill cum barbecue tray with 4 Skewer rods, crumb tray and a rotisserie skewer rod with 2 forks. Two heating elements on the top and two heating elements at the bottom. **No convection fan**. The top and bottom heating elements can be switched on or off independently.

**Question:**
Since it consumes a good amount of electricity, and since baking items separately takes a lot of time, I wanted to know **what items can be baked simultaneously in such an oven**. Items can be placed on the baking tray, rotisserie and the wire rack. I'm hoping the crumb tray can be used as an extra baking tray.

**Searching I've done:**
**On searching the internet** for "How to Cook Multiple Dishes in the Oven at Once" it appeared to give me **answers suited for a much larger oven**. Answers given were about baking cookies, sheet pan meals, pizzas, assorted pastries, muffins, bread or rolls, vegetables, and brownies or blondies. Precautionary points mentioned were about similar sized items, adding items later in the baking process based on how much baking time is required, rotating the tray halfway through, and ensuring there's enough space for air circulation. An [old question here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43176/can-i-cook-2-very-different-things-at-same-time-in-the-oven) was also a bit different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We used an oven approximately this size when our full-sized oven failed at the beginning of the year.  I would not attempt to bake multiple things in it at once.

Even though there are three rack positions, there isn't enough room to stack multiple trays for anything taller than cookies. I wouldn't suggest even doing cookies, because there isn't really air circulation in the oven and the elements and heating are designed to heat a single tray.  For example, if you tried to cook two trays of cookies stacked, what I would expect is that the cookies on the bottom would get burnt on the bottom with the top raw, and the cookies on top would be the reverse.  Yes, you could try swapping top and bottom halfway through cooking, but is it really worth it to save 15min of heating time?

So, that's my answer for you: there aren't any foods such that cooking multiple dishes/trays in an oven that size will work well.

Comment: Yes; some racks being too close to the heating elements was my worry too. Perhaps the rotisserie could be used to cook chicken while a pizza bakes in the middle rack. I wouldn't mind liquid from the chicken dripping onto the pizza.